# Cargar imagen y texto de cada ITEM (ListView) en la misma Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, activity

Como puedo hacer que dentro de esa Activity me cargue el texto y la imagen de mi ListView? (Cada ITEM su imagen y texto, no en todos lo mismo, obviamente)

Mi código:

```
listViewPersonas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba.class);


        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: ¿pero quieres que se muestre la lista y la imagen y el texto a la vez? Lo único que se me ocurre así  es dividir la activity en dos fragments, en uno poner la lista y en el otro el detalle del item

Comment: @Joacer , la lista no, solamente la imagen y el texto, alguna idea para eso? Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @UserNameYo ok , usas un list de objetos? cual es tu objeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que pides se podría resolver con `Fragments`

Puedes crearte una Activity que contenga dos fragments, un Fragment con la lista y otro con la vista de detalles e ir cambiando de una a otra mediante transacciones de Fragments.

Para cambiar entre la vista de lista y la de detalle tendrías que realizar una transacción entre fragments por lo que deberías quitar las líneas del Intent del onClick y sustituirlas por algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
listViewPersonas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

       // Commit the transaction
       transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

A continuación te dejo la documentación de [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) donde puedes informarte en más profundidad.

P.D: ¿Hay alguna razón por la que quieras tenerlo en una misma Actividad, en vez de tenerlo en dos Actividades distintas? Lo digo porque igual resulta más fácil hacerlo en dos Activities.

Comment: Cada item que tengo es un contacto, he creado una activity flotante para que al pulsar encima salga, y ahí quiero que salga la imagen y nombre junto a los botones de editar (llevándote a otra activity) y borrar, qué manera me recomiendas para hacer tal cosa? Fragments ? Gracias de nuevo @Joacer

Comment: Se podría realizar ocultando y mostrando elementos, pero considero que lo mejor es lo que comenta Joacer, que es usar un fragmento, esto para no volver a modificar la UI de la Activity. @UserNameYo

Comment: Se me olvidó esta pregunta, finalmente lo solucione con un `Fragment` como me comentaste, gracias! @Joacer

Comment: @UserNameYo me alegro de que te haya servido mi ayuda!! Gracias